# Downloading file from Web using Powershell or Command Line

Tags: powershell, https, download, command, size

I'm trying to download a file using powershell or command line using the command "Invoke-WebRequest  -O ". File is getting downloaded but the size of the downloaded file is less than compared to actual file.

Comment: Please show us the code you are using right now and try to tell us more about the file you want to download (maybe you can even show us it's contents if it's text-based)

Comment: "Invoke-WebRequest https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H1ercXgIltL-nePC9cgjpYKLPJMtpxR3 -O MTE.sdf"

Comment: File Type : .sdf extension, uploaded on Google drive which I'm trying to download. Actual size: 1252KB, Post download size: 73KB

Comment: It sounds like the file that gets downloaded is not the file, but an HTML page (likely an error). Open it in a text editor and it might reveal the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me even if not based on Invoke-Webrequest

```
$url = "Url to file"
$output = "path to destination file"
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
```